# How can I increase speed of my python program

Tags: python, operating-system

I made a python program. In my program there are two functions first function can search file's folder(path) and second function can search folder's path in code everything is clear, please check it. However, my program runs very slow. How can I increase it's speed. Thank you!

```
import  os
x = 0
#this function can find file's path folder
def find(file, operator, first=False,):
    global x
    print('searching from folder D:\\ ...')

    for d, subD, f in os.walk('D:\\'):
        if file in f:
            print('Found it')
            print("{0}\{1}".format(d,file))
            x = 1
            if first == True:
                break
    else:
        x = 0
        print('couldn\'t find')
        print('searching from folder C:\\ ...')
        for d, subD, f in os.walk('C:\\'):
            if file in f:
                print('Found it')
                print("{0}\{1}".format(d,file))
                x = 1
                if first == True:
                    break
find('Illustrator.exe',x,True)
#output C:\User\Users\Illustrator\Illustrator.exe

#this function can find folder's full path
def find_path(folder_name)
    print('searching...')
    for root, subdirs, files in os.walk('C:\\'):
        for d in subdirs:
            if d == folder_name:
                print('True')
                print(root+'\\'+d)
                break
    else:
        for root, subdirs, files in os.walk('D:\\'):
            for d in subdirs:
                if d == folder_name:
                    print('True')
                    print(root+'\\'+d)
                    break
find_path('Photoshop')
#output C:\User\Users\Photoshop
```

Comment: Have you tried profiling it? Do you know which part is "slow"? We're not going to do this step for you...

Comment: This is a question more suited for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) as the code works, although not efficiently or requires improvement

Comment: @dspencer Hi! None of parts are slow. I just wanted to increase my program's speed

Comment: @Jab Hi! Oh I didn't know about code review. Thank you!